# javascript consistent format of date

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is expecting the startDate and endDate to be in YYYY-mm-dd format as a (String). Because I'm using a couple components/plugins, sometimes the dates are coming in different formats.

If the date comes in as "Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800" format. I want to convert it into YYYY-mm-dd However, if its already in YYYY-mm-dd format, don't touch it.

I tried using something like where I pass in my initial string, but it seems to be messing up my date because of the inconsistent nature of the startDate value.

```
var d = new Date(startDate);

var datestring = d.getDate()  + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " +
d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Define _"messing up"_. Would it not make more sense to fix the problem at the source and have these _"components/plugins"_ produce actual `Date` instances or at worst, ISO 8601 formatted strings?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, but these plugs are not my own and I would rather not customize them and make them not updateable later.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achive the data in `YYYY-mm-dd` format using [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
function getDate(date) {
  return date.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/)
    ? date
    : new Date(date).toISOString().split("T")[0];
}

console.log(getDate("2020-03-12"));
console.log(getDate("Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800"));
console.log(getDate("Wed Dec 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800"));
console.log(getDate("Wed Mar 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800"));
```